# C++ Command Line Argument Identification

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments, double-quotes, command-line-interface

I need to be able to tell if the final argument in my command line is surrounded in double quotes or not.  If it's in double quotes, I treat it as a string.  If it's not, I need to treat it as a file to open and obtain the string.  Argv by default will grab the double quoted string and strip the quotes, so I can't figure out a way to handle this problem.

pseudocode is something like this...

```
if(argv[argc-1] was called with surrounding double quotes){
    //handle as string (I already have code to do this)
}
else{
    //handle as filename (I already have code to do this)
}
```

Comment: How about a command-line argument that you use to decide which is which? (i.e. `-s` for a string and `-f` for a filename)

Comment: You probably need to find a different way of users specifying if it's a string or filename.

Comment: Note that many shells will interpret quotes in their own way, so you might hit some surprises with your design at some point.

Comment: Are you on Windows, and will never ever change to another operating system? Then there may be a chance for you, since the `find` tool also distinguishes quotes from nonquotes. But if you do that, you can no longer have `main` as your starting point.

Answer (score 2):

All of the parameters in argv are strings. You are probably better off rethinking your strategy. Try opening the argument, if that fails then treat it as a string.

Alternatively you could escape the quotes on the command line and they will be passed to your application:

```
$ program "\"this is a string\""
```

**Edit**: The sample code assumes you are using a Bash shell or something similar

Comment: Wouldn't it be `$ program "\"this is a string\""`?

Comment: That would work too, Bash will strip the unescaped quotes. Try it! **Edit**: you're right, I originally tested with a one-word string

Comment: Thanks guys, I have to do it exactly as I stated for a homework assignment, without escaping any characters.  I'm going to try the strategy @Mike Steinert mentioned above: trying to open the file and if it doesn't exists using it as a string.  Clever idea!

Comment: .. except .. what if the user happened to want to specify a string that also just happened to be the name of a file?

Comment: @Jim Buck: This is a good corner case, however I suspect it's not an issue for this particular homework assignment.